# How can I make "Pop out reply" the default behaviour to reply to an email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I would like to make all my replies in Gmail "Pop out" replies such as shown in the screenshot below. Is this somehow possible?

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just learned that by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking the *Reply* button, you get the pop-out window you want.

Also, keyboard shortcuts let you easily open a pop-out menu for replies.
(If you haven't yet enabled Gmail keyboard shortcuts, click the *Settings* cogwheel, select *Settings* from the menu, scroll down to *Keyboard shortcuts*, and select *Keyboard shortcuts on*.)

With keyboard shortcuts enabled, when viewing a message in Gmail, pressing <kbd>R</kbd> opens the reply area below the message.
Instead of pressing <kbd>R</kbd>, press <kbd>Shift+R</kbd>, and the pop-out reply window appears instead.

Source: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594

Answer (score 0):

Add the Auto Bcc for Gmail™ & Inbox™ extension. There is an option in the extension to auto pop out all reply's.

Comment: Are you referring to [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-bcc-for-gmail-inbox/hfjgikgjcgdhlklibkcobckkhklaeodd?hl=en)? If yes, can you please add the link to your answer?